# How to close the program after the user enters a character and presses the enter key?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ programming. My program runs perfectly but i also need it to close when the user enter s a character and presses the enter key. I have no idea how that is supposed to be done. any help will be really appreciated. My code so far is(runs fine) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int money_spent, money_tendered;

    cout << "Enter the total amount spent: \n";
    cin >> money_spent;

    cout << "Enter the amount tendered: \n";
    cin >> money_tendered;

    int balance = money_tendered - money_spent;
    int ten_bills = balance / 1000;
    balance = balance % 1000;
    int five_bills = balance / 500;
    balance = balance % 500;
    int dollar_coins = balance / 100;
    balance = balance % 100;
    int quater_coins = balance / 25;
    balance = balance % 25;
    int dimes = balance / 10;
    balance = balance % 10;
    int nickels = balance / 5;
    balance = balance % 5;
    int pennies = balance;

    cout << " \n \n"
        << "Your change is: \n"
        << ten_bills << " tenn dollar bill(s). \n"
        << five_bills << " five dollar bill(s). \n"
        << dollar_coins << " one dollar coin(s). \n"
        << quater_coins << " quater(s). \n"
        << dimes << " dime(s). \n"
        << nickels << " nickel(s). \n"
        << pennies << " pennie(s). \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have removed the C# tag.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
cin.ignore();    
cin.get();
```

before

```
return 0;
```

You need `cin.ignore()`, to ignore the ENTER you typed after entering `money_tendered`. Otherwise this ENTER will be captured by `cin.get()` instead of the last character you are going to enter.

Comment: i just tried this code i.e, cin.get(); but it didn't work. it still showed the same thing "press any key to continue...."

Comment: @KunalGrover, then add another `cin.get();` or `cin.ignore();` before the first one.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getchar();
```

It's a standard c-function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your cin to read a string.  Then you need to check to see if that string is "s".  If so you want to return 0.  Otherwise you want to convert the string to an integer and store it in money_spent or money_tendered.  Then you want to wrap the entire procedure in a while(1) { } loop so that it doesn't exit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the end of your program.

**system**("pause");

One the application comes to this line it will show you

**Press any key to continue . . .** message. Once you click a button the application automatically exit the process.